# Running session multiple times with tf.random returns different values for conv2d

Tags: random, tensorflow, convolution

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

x_tf = tf.placeholder('float',[None, 2, 5, 1])
x_np = np.random.noraml(0,1,[1,2,5,1])

# ======== filter option1 and option2 ===========
f_np = np.random.normal(0,1,[1,3,1,1])
f_tf = tf.constant(f_np,'float') # option 1
f_tf = tf.random_normal([1,3,1,1]) # option 2
# ===============================================

x_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x_tf,f_tf,[1,1,1,1],'SAME')

with tf.Session() as sess:
     tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
     x_conv_np  = sess.run(x_conv, feed_dict={x_tf: x_np})
     x_conv_np2 = sess.run(x_conv, feed_dict={x_tf: x_np})
```

If I run the code above with option1, I get the same values for `x_conv_np` and `x_conv_np2`
However, when I run the above with option2, I get different values for `x_conv_np` and `x_conv_np2`.

I am guessing the tf.random_normal gets initialized every time the session is ran.
Is this meant to happen?
This happens even if I do the `tf.set_random_seed`
Can someone explain how TensorFlow initializes its random variables when the session is ran?

Comment: Don't you have a typo in your code. Your feed_dict should be `{x_tf: x_np}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the [random number ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/constant_op/random_tensors) in TensorFlow (including [`tf.random_normal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/constant_op/random_tensors#random_normal)) sample a new random tensor each time they runs:

> TensorFlow has several ops that create random tensors with different distributions. The random ops are stateful, and create new random values each time they are evaluated.

If you want to sample the distribution once and then re-use the result, you should use a `tf.Variable` and initialize it by running `tf.random_normal()` once. For example, the following code will print the same random value twice:

```
f_tf = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 3, 1, 1]))
# ...
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# ...
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  print(sess.run(f_tf))
  print(sess.run(f_tf))
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot I had to initialize the weight as tf.Variable(...)